# server socket is the best option to perform

Tags: java, server

I am doubtful on what to use to do this:

I wanted to have a .bat file (which would be open on a machine and through that bat I would be able to have event logs from my application / and would run routines through it like "save a backup").
And my login system would only work if this .bat file is open
something like a "GAMESERVER" (I do not know if this is necessary, but I wanted to do it for training)

I had thought of creating an auxilary table in the database with only 2 fields id / a boolean field.

When you open this. bat would make connection and set that value to 1

and in my login system I would check if this value is 1, and then I could free the login.

I do not know if this is the best way

Or in that case would it be better to use a serversocket?

Could someone give me an example of how I can get started?

Comment: It's always good to come with an idea of what you want to achieve and bring on what you have done so far. So we can help. would you mind to do so?

Comment: In relation to this I still have nothing because I do not know which way better
but I already have all my desktop application done

Comment: I wanted to implement some of this, my login system would only work if one file. bat (which will be on a local server) is open (in this bat I would run my routines and pick up logs)

Comment: Sorry if I was missing information I'm not good at English.

Comment: No problem. Would you mind looking at tutorial on how to get started with Server Socket? 
 You can get a free eBook here https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-sockets

Comment: @GratienAsimbahwe ty bro 
I'm going to start studying about
I do not know if you can understand my goal.
but do you think serversocket is the solution?

Comment: For what you want you don't need a server socket. I posted that link so you can understand what it is. Logging events into a file, you just need the basic understanding of reading/writing into a file. The .bat extension doesn't matter. But if you want your .bat to be executed from command line as batch commands, then the file will need to be a valid batch script

Comment: I understand I will study and train serversocket, even on opening my systems login only if my file. bat is open? would not that need serversocket?

Comment: If you want to create an answer so I can vote positive.

Comment: the answer is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want you don't need a server socket. I posted that link so you can understand what it is. Logging events into a file, you just need the basic understanding of reading/writing into a file. The .bat extension doesn't matter. But if you want your .bat to be executed from command line as batch commands, then the file will need to be a valid batch script.

The question you'll have to ask yourself is: "Who's gonna connect to your server? How?" Then only you can determine what you really need.

Server Sockets are used for live communications:

> Normally, a server runs on a specific computer and has a socket that is bound to a specific port number. The server just waits, listening to the socket for a client to make a connection request.
>
> On the client-side: The client knows the hostname of the machine on which the server is running and the port number on which the server is listening. To make a connection request, the client tries to rendezvous with the server on the server's machine and port. The client also needs to identify itself to the server so it binds to a local port number that it will use during this connection. This is usually assigned by the system.

This comes from : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html

Changing a value from 0 to 1 if connected and from 1 to 0 if not, that's just like saving a preference into a file. and all you need to know for that is how to manipulate files.

Comment: thanks, for finish about this: Who's gonna connect to your server? 
Machines that are connected on the local network where my application is going 
and only one machine (the main one would have that .bat open)

Comment: With that I had some ideas of using files. ini with ini4j to do some things

Comment: think about using a database and set a proper authentication system for your security